# Neopentane melting point

Tags: organic-chemistry, melting-point

Given that neopentane and n-pentane are both hydrocarbons derived from pentane with five carbon atoms each, but differ in their structural arrangements — with neopentane being more branched and n-pentane being a straight-chain isomer — why does neopentane exhibit a higher melting point than n-pentane? How do their molecular structures and the inherent intermolecular forces associated with them influence this difference?
I probably asume that it’s due to its geometry and symmetry, so that it’s easier to pack in solid state, but any more detailed explanation?

Comment: It is boiling that can be explained easily. Melting points are another story altogether. Crystal structures are *tricky*.